# shell script linux,bash : moving files according to name field-1 to the specific path in field-2 using `cut`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cut

I am new in shell, I tried to transfer file in *field-1* into specific folder according to specific path in *field-3* and I hope you can help me.

*this is my text file:*

---

**deleted_files.txt**

```
ohdah1.sql 5075 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\ 
sourcetreeconfig 1066 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\ 
commit-msg.sample 896 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
post-receive.sample 552 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
pre-commit.sample 1704 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
pre-push.sample 1348 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
pre-rebase.sample 4951 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
prepare-commit-msg.sample 1239 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
update.sample 3611 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\hooks\ 
HEAD 821 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\logs\ 
master 821 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\.git\logs\refs\heads\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\cache\ 
autoload.php 3256 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
constants.php 1598 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
database.php 3288 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
doctypes.php 1152 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
foreign_chars.php 1844 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
migration.php 1322 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
mimes.php 4559 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
routes.php 2909 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
smileys.php 3360 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\config\ 
device.php 18797 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\controllers\ 
get_password.php 1632 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\controllers\ 
gfp.php 2958 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\controllers\ 
user.php 5374 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\controllers\ 
my_model.php 2316 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\core\ 
error_404.php 1221 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\errors\ 
error_general.php 1208 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\errors\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\errors\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\helpers\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\hooks\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\language\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\language\english\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\libraries\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\logs\ 
trusteeship_m.php 1147 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\models\ 
user_m.php 3048 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\models\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\third_party\ 
email_check.php 924 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\ 
gp_form.php 1167 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\ 
pageNotFound.php 2090 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\ 
add.php 5059 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\car\ 
carTabs.php 1725 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\car\ 
conf.php 2909 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\car\ 
handit.php 1971 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\car\ 
viewU.php 3016 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\car\ 
add.php 3525 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\device\ 
conf.php 2563 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\device\ 
confR.php 3259 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\device\ 
deviceTabs.php 1720 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\device\ 
handit.php 1662 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\device\ 
viewU.php 2807 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\device\ 
add.php 3457 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\gis\ 
conf.php 2548 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\gis\ 
confR.php 3042 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\gis\ 
gisTabs.php 1642 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\gis\ 
handit.php 1603 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\gis\ 
viewU.php 2816 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\gis\ 
view.php 1810 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\search\ 
header.php 929 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\templates\ 
add.php 6606 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\user\ 
changePassword.php 2681 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\user\ 
userTabs.php 1043 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\application\views\user\ 
bootstrap-theme.min.css 13191 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
dataTables.bootstrap.css 7088 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
green.png 2219 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
green@2x.png 4524 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
style.css 7590 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
sweet-alert.css 14949 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
sweet-alert.html 754 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\css\ 
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 41280 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\fonts\ 
back_enabled.jpg 833 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\images\ 
forward_enabled.jpg 878 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\images\ 
icheck.min.js 4957 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\js\ 
sweet-alert.js 21768 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\assets\js\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\ 
Benchmark.php 3066 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Common.php 13980 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Controller.php 1628 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Exceptions.php 4887 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Hooks.php 4944 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Lang.php 3792 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Model.php 1246 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Router.php 12915 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
Utf8.php 3748 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\core\ 
DB.php 4351 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\ 
DB_cache.php 4572 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\ 
DB_utility.php 10217 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\ 
cubrid_forge.php 7346 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\cubrid\ 
cubrid_result.php 4707 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\cubrid\ 
cubrid_utility.php 2978 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\cubrid\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\cubrid\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mssql\ 
mssql_driver.php 15502 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mssql\ 
mssql_result.php 3541 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mssql\ 
mssql_utility.php 2065 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mssql\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysql\ 
mysql_driver.php 18149 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysql\ 
mysql_result.php 3798 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysql\ 
mysql_utility.php 4819 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysql\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysqli\ 
mysqli_driver.php 18184 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysqli\ 
mysqli_result.php 3814 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysqli\ 
mysqli_utility.php 2070 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\mysqli\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\oci8\ 
oci8_forge.php 5857 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\oci8\ 
oci8_utility.php 2015 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\oci8\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\odbc\ 
odbc_driver.php 14530 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\odbc\ 
odbc_forge.php 6382 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\odbc\ 
odbc_utility.php 2362 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\odbc\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\pdo\ 
pdo_utility.php 2339 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\pdo\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\postgre\ 
postgre_forge.php 7648 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\postgre\ 
postgre_result.php 3605 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\postgre\ 
postgre_utility.php 1942 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\postgre\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlite\ 
sqlite_driver.php 14712 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlite\ 
sqlite_result.php 3727 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlite\ 
sqlite_utility.php 2244 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlite\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\ 
sqlsrv_forge.php 6144 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\ 
sqlsrv_result.php 3584 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\ 
sqlsrv_utility.php 2066 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\fonts\ 
array_helper.php 2627 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
captcha_helper.php 6414 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
cookie_helper.php 2693 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
directory_helper.php 2141 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
download_helper.php 2853 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
email_helper.php 1544 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
html_helper.php 9231 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
inflector_helper.php 5569 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
language_helper.php 1466 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
number_helper.php 1934 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
path_helper.php 1850 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
security_helper.php 2802 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
smiley_helper.php 6746 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
string_helper.php 6739 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
typography_helper.php 2331 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
xml_helper.php 1858 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\helpers\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\ 
calendar_lang.php 1487 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
car_lang.php 677 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
db_lang.php 2301 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
email_lang.php 1730 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
form_validation_lang.php 1847 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
ftp_lang.php 1302 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
imglib_lang.php 2034 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
migration_lang.php 727 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
profiler_lang.php 1141 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
unit_test_lang.php 832 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
upload_lang.php 1640 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\arabic\ 
calendar_lang.php 1487 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
db_lang.php 2301 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
email_lang.php 1730 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
form_validation_lang.php 1847 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
ftp_lang.php 1302 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
imglib_lang.php 2034 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
migration_lang.php 727 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
profiler_lang.php 1141 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
unit_test_lang.php 832 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
upload_lang.php 1640 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\language\english\ 
Calendar.php 13141 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Driver.php 5564 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Javascript.php 20987 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Log.php 2809 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Migration.php 8322 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Pagination.php 9392 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Profiler.php 19856 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Sha1.php 5245 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Table.php 11899 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Unit_test.php 8582 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Upload.php 28684 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\ 
Cache.php 4778 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\ 
Cache_apc.php 3342 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\drivers\ 
Cache_dummy.php 2690 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\drivers\ 
Cache_file.php 4187 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\drivers\ 
Cache_memcached.php 5121 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\drivers\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\Cache\drivers\ 
index.html 123 C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\system\libraries\javascript\ 
</b>
```

---

and this is my script

**my script**:

```
for i in cat deleted_files.txt; 
do file = ls | cut -f1 -d' ' $i;
path = cut -f3 -d' ' $i;
mv -r $file $path; 
done
```

---

Comment: You're trying to move files listed in "deleted_files.txt" to whatever folder is also listed in "deleted_files.txt"? And you're pipeing `ls` why? When I pipe anything into a `cut` that's reading from a file (the `$i` here) it ignores the piped input and only reads the file. And when I run `for i in cat tst; do echo $i; done` it echo's `cat` and `tst` (I have an existing file called "tst")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this script is you want to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  file=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
  path=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f3)

  ## If file exists, then move to path
  [[ -f $file ]] && mv $file $path
done < deleted_files.txt
```

By the way, column_3 looks like Windows path format. Does your system recognize `C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\` is path format? If not, file name will change "ohdah1.sql" to `C:\Users\TALAL\Desktop\backup_ohdah\26\ohdah\`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this, assuming you're in the current directory containing the files listed in "deleted_files.txt".

```
while read -r i
do echo "$i"
file=$(echo "$i"|cut -d' ' -f1)
echo "file is $file"
path=$(echo "$i"|cut -d' ' -f3)
echo "path is $path"
mv "$file" "$path"
done < tst
```

There are several echo's thrown in there to make sure it'll do what you want (try it without the `mv` first to make sure).

And I'm not sure why you were doing the `ls`, maybe to verify that the file exists first? Could use bash's "`[[`  compound  command  and  the `test` and `[` builtin commands to test file attributes" with "`-a file`  True if file exists."

Comment: nice this was help to ensure that file and path are both on the same line